# anchor tag not working when adding margin to parent or child elements

Tags: html, css, icons, css-position, anchor

I have an `icon` nested inside an `anchor` tag, it works but only when hovering over the very top of the icon, no matter what size the icon element is.

```
<div class="icon">
  <a id="fb-icon-link" href="https://www.facebook.com/jameschristopherpotter" target="_blank">
    <span class="fb-span">
      <i class="fab fa-facebook fa-4x fb-icon" area-hidden="true"></i>
    </span>
  </a>
</div>
```

I tried moving it to a lower position in order to make it easier for the person to click on it but when I try adding a margin or any other property to the anchor tag, to its parent (`div`) or child (`icon`), the link doesn't work anymore. I tried adding a `z-index` to the anchor tag in case it was behind the div or something but it didn't work. Btw, I added `position: absolute` to the parent `div` in order to make sure it would stay on the top right corner, not sure if that's affecting.

Here's the css:

```
#fb-icon-link {
  color: black;
}

.fb-icon:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.icon{
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

Completely puzzled, never seen this behavior before. Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What version of fontawesome are you using, 5.?.

Comment: I can’t reproduce the problem, using fontawesome v5.15.2 and trying margin set on the a element. Could you put up a complete snippet which has the problem?

Comment: Hey, guys. Thanks for your comments, I found the issue, one div had a z-index of 2 and it was covering the icon.